# Change NSTimer speed with variable?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a timer that launches in viewDidLoad that looks like this

`[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.001f target:self selector:@selector(Dragon:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];`

I want to be able to change my Interval with a variable.  However, any time I try to place a variable where the 0.001f is I get errors... any ideas?

Comment: There should be no issue with passing in a `float` variable into that method, what errors do you get?

Comment: Try 0.01f, what is the exact error?

Comment: Whoops I was using an int and not a float *blushes*  I am using this timer to control the speed a character I have moves at... once I close the app and reopen it the characters speed doesn't reset to the default, how do I fix this now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an app that does exactly what you are asking. I allow the user to change the speed of the timer within the app so I need to make that speed a variable. Here's how I did it:

1. I create a timer property on my main view controller class.
2. I initialize the timer when the main view controller class loads.
3. Each time thereafter, I invalidate my timer and reset it when the value changes.

**Some snippets from inside of my main view controller .m file:**

```
    //How often to switch views (float)
    #define kInterval [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"interval"]

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self setTimer];
}

- (void) setTimer{
    [self.timer invalidate];
    [self setTimer: [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:kInterval target:self selector:@selector(timerFired) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]];
}
```

Comment: You might want to change the method name to `resetTimer`, but +1 nevertheless.

Comment: I use this initially, so I called it setTimer. I should put a check in there for a nil timer, though.

Answer (score 0):

Is the app returning from a background process? If so, you may need to re-set the timer. You might also want to peek at CADisplayLink: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009031

Comment: How do you reset a timer? I think I need to reset the timer every time the float I have controlling the increment changes...

Comment: Maintain a reference to it. Then, when appropriate, `invalidate` it, and re-create a timer with the new varible.

Comment: How would i maintain a refereference to it... sorry I have never worked with timers before :o and I cant find it in the documentation thankyou for all the help so far though

Comment: Use an NSTimer variable in your object. Something like `NSTimer *aTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.001f target:self selector:@selector(Dragon:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];` (taken from your example). You can then `[aTimer invalidate]` when you need to. NOTE: NSRunLoop will retain/release the timer, so you may need to nil out the variable before reusing it.

Comment: I have an app that does exactly what you are asking. I allow the user to change the speed of the timer within the app so I need to make that speed a variable. Let me go check. Hang on.

Answer (score 0):

@King Popsicle you can take help of this method

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication  *)application OR
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication  *)application

You can fix the things in this method regarding the timer values :)